# Unable to update ubuntu 20.04 on EC2 owing to timeout

Tags: networking, apt, updates, amazon-ec2

I've got what could either be a problem with an EC2 instance or with ubuntu 20.04.

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I eventually get:

```
Failed to fetch http://eu-west-
2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to eu-
west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.241.117.189), connection timed out Could not 
connect to eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.246.214.20), connection timed out
```

The attached security group allows http/s traffic.
Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong?

**Adding outbound rules**

[image]

Comment: Very clear message the access to this eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com is timing out. Try another mirror.

Comment: Check once outbound traffic too or try to download anything using wget if it works than there might be issue with the mirrors.

Comment: @David before outputting this message it cycles through different mirrors, I wasn't mindful of this when I posted. I guess that points to a networking issue.

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal ah that's very helpful, yeah I can't download so much as jquery without a time out, so I must need to change my security group in some way.

Comment: @goose Please check outbound security group once.

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal - sure thing. I've added a picture showing the attached outbound rules.

Comment: @goose where you have added the picture ?

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal to the bottom of the question. It doesn’t stand out very well as it’s white on white.